# What is the history of the phrase "figure it out"?

Tags: etymology, dialects

Just trying to establish the time when the term came into popular use in the US or elsewhere.  Google didn't tell me.

Answer (score 5):

**figure out**

> To work out (a sum) by means of figures; more widely to estimate or
> calculate; hence to work out; make out. Chiefly *U.S.*
>
> **1833** As I said before I'm stump'd about that Bank of US; and I want
> you to help me figure it out. OED

I found these early examples with Google Books:

> "Well, Mr. Clerk, ... you have been **figuring it out** for me on paper; has he got it right?"
> "Yes, Madam," said the clerk, taking his long calculation out of his
> pocket, "he has got it exactly. And, I venture to say that there is not another man on the island that can do it in two hours." [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Varieties_of_Human_Greatness_A_Disco/GLNcAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22figuring%20it%20out%22&pg=PA27&printsec=frontcover). (1838)

> "Sure enough, brother Cap, your question is more easily put than
> answered. Is there no such thing as **figuring it out**  by
> navigation? I thought you salt-water mariners were able to do as small a
> thing as that. I have often read of their discovering islands,
> surely."  James Fenimore Cooper, *[The Pathfinder](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Pathfinder/AVOt291HXVcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22figuring%20it%20out%22&pg=PA189&printsec=frontcover)* (1840) p.189

As Andrew Leach points out in his answer, there is a broadening in meaning of *to figure out* from *to work out/understand via calculation* to its more general meaning. This is similar to what happened with the verb *[to reckon](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=reckon)* centuries earlier.

The meaning becomes more figurative—wait, no, less "figurative" :-)

Answer (score 3):

The thing to do is to use [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22+figure+it+out+%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20figure%20it%20out%20%22%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%22%20figure%20it%20out%20%22%3B%2Cc0) which would indicate 1885 for the first appearance in print.

One can then tweak a [Books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%22%20figure%20it%20out%20%22%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1860,cd_max:1885&lr=lang_en) (using the buttons at the bottom of the chart and changing the dates in the URL) to find an occurrence in **1867**:

> I can't be positive about it, but I believe I did figure it out.

That usage refers to calculation, because the next question is "Was your estimate higher or lower than £55000?" The verb appears to be similar to "put it out" — the result drops out of a calculation involving the manipulation of figures.

It's a short hop from calculating a value to working out how a particular situation arose. By 1918 the phrase appears in a car workshop manual:

> Find if it is ignition, carburetion, cooling, or just what the trouble is, and then figure it out the best you can before proceeding.
>
> — [*Dyke's Automobile and Gasoline Engine Encyclopedia*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=A1xIAQAAMAAJ&q=%22+figure+it+out+%22&dq=%22+figure+it+out+%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis94qIq8TyAhXXi1wKHRzZDqY4tAEQ6AEwBHoECAgQAg)

Comment: You apparently only searched for the Present Tense / Infinitive verb version. I checked for Past Tense and found this from *The Life of P.T.Barnum, Written by Himself* - ["I think," I replied, "it is 999 years, but I have almost forgotten, as it is some years since I figured it out."](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22years+since+i+figured+it+out%22) But as with your own example, most such early usages obviously more strongly allude to the "original, underlying" literal sense of "calculation".